# How to find out which situation has the most missing data

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this (df)

| ID | Community | Time | BIP | EXP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | BF | 12000 | 500 |
| 1 | 1 | DF | NA | NA |
| 1 | 1 | AF | 8000 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | BF | 13000 | 300 |
| 2 | 1 | DF | 12000 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | AF | 11000 | 120 |

This df has 40'000 observations. I would like to find out which of these situation in the time column (BF= Before financial crisis; DF = during finance crisis; AF= After Finance Crisis) has the most missing data in all the columns BIP and EXP?

I gave the following code to find out how many missing data are in BIP and EXP

```
sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

It shows that BIP has 55 missing data and EXP has 34 missing data. But no information for the time situation.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`:

```r
aggregate(cbind(BIP = is.na(BIP), EXP = is.na(EXP)) ~ Time, data = dat, sum)
#Also works
#with(dat, aggregate(list(BIP = BIP, EXP = EXP), list(Time = Time), function(x) sum(is.na(x))))

  Time BIP EXP
1   AF   0   1
2   BF   0   0
3   DF   1   1
```

---

Or in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(Time) %>% 
  summarise(across(BIP:EXP, ~ sum(is.na(.x))))

  Time    BIP   EXP
1 AF        0     1
2 BF        0     0
3 DF        1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, colSums(is.na(.SD)), by = Time, .SDcols = BIP:EXP]
```